# Not able to boot from USB SSD / Booterrors /SSD unmounts after time

Tags: pi-4, usb, boot-issues, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, raspbian-lite

**Hi guys

So long Story short:

I have:
Raspberry PI 4B 8 GB
WD red SA500 2TB NAS 2.5" SSD
Delock USB 3.0 to SATA adapter
and a ICY BOX USB 3.2 gen 1 External powered USB hub (to prevent power issues)

First of all i installed Raspberry pi os lite 64bit with the whole LAMP package for a webserver. After that i also decided to install Samba and Plex media server on it.

after that i bought the ssd for all my movies for Plex and first it seems to work and i mounted it on /hdd. i could upload my movies but as i want to read my inventory on plex with the path of the ssd there came a network error and after that the ssd unmounts itself. this happens all the time and then i decided to install the whole system just on the SSD.

So i did. I could install Raspberry pi os on the ssd without any problems. i started the boot process first without any problems but it was damn slow.

At a certain point from the boot status checks (the ones with the Ok boot statuses) there came a lot of errors and i noticed that my usb Ports were disabled.

Can you guys help me because i tried to fix it for a week now and i dont know where the problem is.

Sry for the bad english because im from Swizerland**

Comment: what chipset does the *Delock USB 3.0 to SATA adapter* use?

Comment: it use the JMicron JMS578 Chipset

Comment: Doesn't surprise me that it's JMicron - I've had nothing but trouble with JMS561U - won't boot anywhere, neither Pi nor desktop PC - not sure if the JMS578 is any better

Comment: now i ordered a new ssd case: i thought that it might be the usb sata converter because i was unable to boot from my desktop too soo this is the new one: https://icybox.de/product/externe_speicherloesungen/IB-382H-C31

Comment: No idea if that uses a different chipset :p

Comment: i couldnt find the infos eighter but when it arrived i give a status update

Comment: Ok here the update. It was the adapter. With the new case it workes just fine:)

Comment: Thanks for the update - another nail in the JMicron coffin as far as I'm concerned :p